# Operation on 2D list

Tags: python-3.x

How do I remove all `['a',*]` from below 2D list:

```
test=[['a',1],['a',2],['a',3],['a',4],['b',1],['b',2],['b',3],['b',4],['c',1],['c',2],['c',3],['c',4],['d',1],['d',2],['d',3],['d',4]]
```

I also wonder if there is an option to create the above pattern?
I am doing some homework projects for practice and to begin with, I stumble here.

(I am very much new to python3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test=[['a',1],['a',2],['a',3],['a',4],['b',1],['b',2],['b',3],['b',4],['c',1],['c',2],['c',3],['c',4],['d',1],['d',2],['d',3],['d',4]]
test=[lst for lst in test if lst[0] != 'a']
print(test)
>>> [['b', 1], ['b', 2], ['b', 3], ['b', 4], ['c', 1], ['c', 2], ['c', 3], ['c', 4], ['d', 1], ['d', 2], ['d', 3], ['d', 4]]
```

i don't understand what you mean by "creating the above pattern". maybe for creating test in the first place?

```
a=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
b=[1,2,3,4]
test=[[x, y] for x in a for y in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> [x for x in test if x[0] != 'a']
[['b', 1], ['b', 2], ['b', 3], ['b', 4], ['c', 1], ['c', 2], ['c', 3], ['c', 4], ['d', 1], ['d', 2], ['d', 3], ['d', 4]]
>>>
```

Or use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [y for key, l in groupby(test, key=lambda x: x[0] != 'a') if key for y in l]
[['b', 1], ['b', 2], ['b', 3], ['b', 4], ['c', 1], ['c', 2], ['c', 3], ['c', 4], ['d', 1], ['d', 2], ['d', 3], ['d', 4]]
>>>
```